# Laravel Eloquent ORM - return objects thru another objects

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent, relation

I have 3 models: Shop, Products and Tags. Shop and Products are in one to many relation, and Products to Tags many to many.

I want to grab for each Shop all unique Tags (since many products can have same tags).

```
class Shop extends Eloquent {

    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany('Product');
    }
}


class Product extends Eloquent {

    public function shop() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Shop');
    }

    public function tags() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag');
    }
}

class Tag extends Eloquent {

    public function products() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Product');
    }
}
```

One of the solutions that I came up with is following. Problem is that I don't get unique tags. There is a solution to put another foreach loop to go thru tags array and compare id in tag object. I would like to optimize a little bit, what do you think is better/cleaner solution?

```
class Shop extends Eloquent {

    ...

    public function getTagsAttribute() {
        $tags = array();
        foreach($this->products as $product)
        {
            foreach ($product->tags as $tag)
            {
                $tags[] = $tag;
            }
        }

        return $tags;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@WereWolf's method will work for you, however here's a trick that will work for all the relations:

```
$shop = Shop::with(['products.tags' => function ($q) use (&$tags) {
  $tags = $q->get()->unique();
}])->find($someId);

// then:
$tags; // collection of unique tags related to your shop through the products
```

Mind that each of the `$tags` will have `pivot` property, since it's a `belongsToMany` relation, but obviously you don't rely on that.

Comment: Yeah, just worth noting: it executes additional query to fetch those tags. That's downside, but still it is by far the easiest solution to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you may try this:

```
$tags = Tag::has('products')->get();
```

This will return all the `Tags` that's bound to any `Product`. If necessary, you may also use `distinct`, like this, but I think it's not necessary in this case:

```
$tags = Tag::has('products')->distinct()->get();
```

**Update:** Then you may try something like this:

```
public function getTagsAttribute()
{
    $shopId = $this->id;

    $tags = Tag::whereHas('products', function($query) use($shopId) {
        $query->where('products.shop_id', $shopId);
    })->get();

    return $tags;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to get unique tags that belongs to specific shop.. There is a model between

Comment: Great work, thanks very much. This is what I've been looking for